# Add reference to ASP.NET 5 Class Library from Framework 4.5 Class Library Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to add reference to ASP.NET 5 Class Library project from regular Framework 4.5 Class Library Project.
I cannot do it.
Is there some workaround and will this be supported?
I have tried to add dependency to framework 4.5 in project.json like this:

```
 "frameworks": {

        "net451": {
            "dependencies": {
                 "System.Data.Common": "1.0.0-beta1",
                "System.Data.SqlClient": "1.0.0-beta1"
            },
            "frameworkAssemblies": {

            }

        },
```

And after this add reference to this ASP.NET 5 Class Library project but without success.

Comment: Your class library is build in the `artifacts\bin\[CONFIGURATION]\[FRAMEWORK]` by VS, then you can add a reference from this build output I guess

Comment: @aguafrommars I cannot see any dll-s in artifacts folders. All folders are empty.

Comment: oh yes, excuse me, it is by publishing, not a simple build

Comment: maybe a `kvm build` in a post build event can do the trick

Comment: oups we don't have post build event in ASP.Net Class Library, but we have "Produce outputs on build", it can do the trick as well. that push dll into the artifacts folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the "Produce outputs on build" checkbox will copy build outputs to `artifacts\bin\[CONFIGURATION]\[FRAMEWORK]` folder

[image]

then you can reference this dll

Comment: I have just referenced dll in Framework4.5 folder from old project type and  it just works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it! First we need to understand that "old-style" projects output and reference DLLs. The ASP.NET 5 projects output and reference NuGet packages.

First set up a local nuget repository. Luckily this can be a folder. Then add that to folder NuGet.Config file.

```
<config>
 <add key="localrepo" value="C:\Temp" />
 <the rest of your file />
</config>
```

You can also do this through the Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources window in Visual Studio.

Then navigate your commandline to the ASP.NET 5 class library you want to reference. Drag down the dependencies with

```
kpm restore
```

Then build and pack it and output the result to your local repository folder.

```
kpm pack --out C:\Temp
```

Now you should be able to add the nupkg from kpm pack as a nuget reference in your "old style" project. Use your normal way of Managing NuGet Packages from Visual Studio if you wish.

Note: Your ASP.NET 5 class library needs to target net45 for this to work. Make sure this is in the framework section of your project.json

```
...
"frameworks": {
        "net45": {},
        // Other frameworks
  }
...
```

Alternatively:
If you want to do it quick and dirty you can run

```
kpm build
```

, and add a direct DLL reference. The DLLs location should be listen in the output from kpm build.

Comment: Sounds pretty complicated to do simple project reference. I was thinking that I just need to add framework - > net45 section in project.json in vNext class library and when I build project it will also output old style DLL-s which can be referenced...

Comment: Yeah it's not pretty. If you want to do it quick and dirty you can run kpm build, and add a direct DLL reference. The DLLs location should be listen in the output from kpm build. Hopefully these nice to have tooling features will make it smoother and smoother as we get closer to release.